# User pictures with transparency

Tags: mojave, login-screen

Has anyone been able to successfully get a user picture with transparency on the Mojave login screen?

I have been using [this old hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080328141726511) for years to do this, but with Mojave, it doesn't seem to work.  The transparent area shows up grey instead.